# Get columns of the columns table

Tags: sql, metadata, sql-server-2014

How can I get the list of columns of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view?

I can get the columns of any table I create using:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

The result set includes multiple columns, such as:

- `TABLE_CATALOG`
- `TABLE_SCHEMA`
- `TABLE_NAME`
- `COLUMN_NAME`
- `DATA_TYPE`
- etc.

How can I get the full list of these columns? It seems that the `COLUMNS` view does not include its columns *in itself* (as in Oracle, PostgreSQL, or MySQL). If I run:

```
select * 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'COLUMNS'
```

I get nothing. Maybe I'm searching in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
     N'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS', NULL, 0);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9b791d2b849c904d746014f40c0290f)**

Comment: Oh... that's sly!

Comment: @TheImpaler I prefer describe_first_result_set because it has column `system_type_name` which is handy when you perform a dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server hold its metadata under the `sys` schema.
`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` was added later on as part of the SQL ISO complience.

```
select   s.name as schema_name
        ,o.name as table_name
        ,c.name as column_name
        ,t.name as type_name
from         sys.schemas        s
        join sys.all_objects    o on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
        join sys.all_columns    c on c.object_id = o.object_id
        join sys.types          t on t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id and t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
where   s.name = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
    and o.name = 'COLUMNS'
```

.

```
+--------------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------+
|    schema_name     | table_name |       column_name        | type_name |
+--------------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------+
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | TABLE_CATALOG            | nvarchar  |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | TABLE_SCHEMA             | nvarchar  |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | TABLE_NAME               | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | COLUMN_NAME              | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | ORDINAL_POSITION         | int       |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | COLUMN_DEFAULT           | nvarchar  |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | IS_NULLABLE              | varchar   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | DATA_TYPE                | nvarchar  |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | int       |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH   | int       |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | NUMERIC_PRECISION        | tinyint   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX  | smallint  |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | NUMERIC_SCALE            | int       |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | DATETIME_PRECISION       | smallint  |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG    | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA     | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | CHARACTER_SET_NAME       | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | COLLATION_CATALOG        | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | COLLATION_SCHEMA         | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | COLLATION_NAME           | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | DOMAIN_CATALOG           | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | DOMAIN_SCHEMA            | sysname   |
| INFORMATION_SCHEMA | COLUMNS    | DOMAIN_NAME              | sysname   |
+--------------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Is there any way of retrieving the data types as string? It seems it's showing them in the form of a code, that I don't know how to decipher.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. I assume `sysname` is just another form of `nvarchar`.

Comment: @TheImpaler - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15